# Xcode wireless build over ethernet?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, wireless, ethernet

As we know Xcode 9 can build without the need of a wire attached to the device, but it seems that the computer **must** be connected **over Wi-Fi** on the same network.

Is there a way to tell Xcode that the computer is on the same network as the iDevice.

[image: Second checkbox is missing]

Second checkbox (Connect via network) is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! Available in Xcode 9.2 (not sure if it's the first version in which it is available):

[image: Connect via network]